# Identify Google Maps Polyline on Click

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, polyline

I have about 200 Polylines on my Map.
Now i try to find out witch Polyline the User have Click.
But polyline.getId() give me every Time a new random number like PL65 next start of the App PL144 and so on.

Is there any Way to know witch Polyline the user have click ?
I must show for every Polyline a Text with rules.

```js
   PolylineOptions spss7 = new PolylineOptions() 
       .add(new LatLng(52.260803, 8.16152))
       .add(new LatLng(52.259113, 8.162186))
       .add(new LatLng(52.258438, 8.158634))
       .color(Color.GREEN)
       .geodesic(true);
   Polyline psps7 = googleMap.addPolyline(spss7);
   psps7.setClickable(true);

   PolylineOptions spss8 = new PolylineOptions()  
       .add(new LatLng(52.3524987, 7.709607499999999))
       .add(new LatLng(52.3524921, 7.7098328))
       .add(new LatLng(52.3534915, 7.710031300000001))
       .color(Color.GREEN)
       .geodesic(true);
       Polyline psps8 = googleMap.addPolyline(spss8);
       psps8.setClickable(true);
    }
       googleMap.setOnPolylineClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener(){
       public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline) {
                   int strokeColor = polyline.getColor() ^ 0x0000CC00;
                   polyline.setColor(strokeColor);
                   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Polyline klick: "+polyline.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                       }
```

Comment: Hey Marcus, did you get the solution for this?

Comment: Yes, i have found a solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [polyline tag](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)) to identify the polyline.

```
           PolylineOptions spss7 = new PolylineOptions() 
           .add(new LatLng(52.260803, 8.16152))
           .add(new LatLng(52.259113, 8.162186))
           .add(new LatLng(52.258438, 8.158634))
           .color(Color.GREEN)
           .geodesic(true);
       Polyline psps7 = googleMap.addPolyline(spss7);
       psps7.setClickable(true);
       psps7.setTag(new String("psps7"));

       PolylineOptions spss8 = new PolylineOptions()  
           .add(new LatLng(52.3524987, 7.709607499999999))
           .add(new LatLng(52.3524921, 7.7098328))
           .add(new LatLng(52.3534915, 7.710031300000001))
           .color(Color.GREEN)
           .geodesic(true);
           Polyline psps8 = googleMap.addPolyline(spss8);
           psps8.setClickable(true);
           psps8.setTag(new String("psps8"));
        }
           googleMap.setOnPolylineClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener(){
           public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline) {
                       int strokeColor = polyline.getColor() ^ 0x0000CC00;
                       polyline.setColor(strokeColor);
                       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Polyline klick: " +
                       (String)polyline.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                           }
```

We set the tag for the 2 polylines in this example then in the onClickListener we get the tag and cast it back to a string.